# Python contour plotting wrong values with plot_surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I want to plot a surface in Matplotlib consisting of zeros everywhere, except for a rectangular region centered in (0, 0), with sides (Dx, Dy), consisting of ones - kind of like a table, if you wil; I can do that using the `plot_surface` command, no worries there. I also want to plot its projections in the "x" and "y" directions (as in [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo3.html)) and that's when the results become weird: Python seems to be interpolating my amplitude values (which, again, should be either zero or one) for the contour plots and showing some lines with values that do not correspond to my data points.

This is what I'm doing:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

Dx = 1.    # Define the sides of the rectangle
Dy = 2.

x_2D = numpy.linspace(-Dx, Dx, 100)     # Create the mesh points
y_2D = numpy.linspace(-Dy, Dy, 100)
x_mesh, y_mesh = numpy.meshgrid(x_2D, y_2D)

rect_2D = numpy.zeros(x_mesh.shape)    # All values of "rect_2D" are zero...
for i in range(x_2D.size):
    for j in range(y_2D.size):
        if numpy.abs(x_mesh[i, j]) <= Dx/2 and numpy.abs(y_mesh[i, j]) <= Dy/2:
            rect_2D[i, j] = 1.         # ... except these ones

fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(9, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x_mesh, y_mesh, rect_2D, alpha=0.3)

ax.contour(x_mesh, y_mesh, rect_2D, zdir='x', offset=-1.5, cmap=pylab.cm.brg)
ax.contour(x_mesh, y_mesh, rect_2D, zdir='y', offset=3, cmap=pylab.cm.brg)

ax.set_xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)
ax.set_zlim(0., 1.5)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

The resulting figure has a dark green line with amplitude a bit below 0.8 on both the "x" and "y" projections, which does not exist in my "rect_2D" variable. Does anyone knows if this is a bug or if there is a mistake in my code? Any suggestions on how to get rid of it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to know, that a numpy code can run vectorised and have much faster execution than **nested for loops**. Going from 36300+ [usec] down to about 340 [usec] **makes more than 100x faster processing IMHO worth mentioning.** Vectorised numpy syntax looks this way:  **`rect_2D[:,:] = 1 * ( ( numpy.abs( x_mesh ) <= DxHalf ) * ( numpy.abs( y_mesh ) <= DyHalf ) )`**

Comment: Thanks user3666197, that was worth mentioning indeed! I do try to use vectorised codes whenever I remember, but old habits die hard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `levels = [0],` kwarg to your `ax.contour` call. This specifies where along the `zdir` axis your contours are computed.  See `mpl.axes.Axes.contour` docstring for more info.

The problem is that without specifying `levels`, contour automatically computes the locations to plot contours and one of these contours is selected just past the 'edge of your table', but before your Zdata is 0. At these points contour interpolates between 0 and 1.

Comment: Hi farenorth, that was spot on! I did imagine Matplotlib would have some way to define which contours are plotted, but I wouldn't expect it to interpolate the data if none was given. Thanks!